# Delphi: CopyFileEx and Thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, file-copying

I have a thread and a Progress Routine (a function) inside it (in my thread class).

I try to do this inside the thread:

```
CopyFileEx(pchar(ListToCopy.Strings[Loop]),pchar(TN+ExtractFileName(ListToCopy.Strings[Loop])), @ProgressRoutine, nil, nil, 0);
```

But I get an error: "Variable required" (the error is in this: **@ProgressRoutine**). If to make the function ProgressRoutine outside the thread then all will be normal.

How to use that function inside thread?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you say "outside the thread" and "inside the thread", do you mean "as a standalone function" and "as a member of the thread object"?  Because if a function is a member of an object, its signature is different, so it doesn't match what the compiler is expecting.

The way you can resolve this is to pass `Self` to `CopyFileEx` as the `lpData` parameter.  This gives it a pointer that it will pass back to the callback.  Write your callback as a standalone function that interprets the `lpData` parameter as a thread object reference and uses that to call the method on your thread object with the same parameters.

**EDIT:** Simple example.  Let's say that the callback only has two parameters, called "value" and "lpData":

```
procedure ProgressRoutine(value: integer; lpData: pointer); stdcall;
var
  thread: TMyThreadClass;
begin
  thread := lpData;
  thread.ProgressRoutine(value);
end;

procedure TMyThreadClass.ProgressRoutine(value: integer);
begin
  //do something with the value here
end;

procedure TMyThreadClass.Execute;
begin
  CopyFileEx(pchar(ListToCopy.Strings[Loop]),pchar(TN+ExtractFileName(ListToCopy.Strings[Loop])), @ProgressRoutine, Self, nil, 0);
  //passing Self to lpData; it will get passed back to the callback
end;
```

Comment: thanks!!! Could you write 2 strings of a code please? Unfortunately, I didn't exactly understand what to do.

Comment: @Maxfax: There, I updated it with a simplified example.  You should be able to extrapolate the actual callback from there.

Comment: A non stdcall function passed as callback to a windows api function?

Comment: @Marco: Like I said, this is a simplified example.

Comment: Added stdcall declaration. Simplifed <> Wrong.